# Android-save date and time into mysql

Tags: php, android, mysql

I am trying to make an android application that can save date and time into mysql. When i try to save there is an error.Here is the android code:

```js
public class CustomerBookingActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

    private static final String TAG = "CustomerBookingActivity";

    private Button pickupDate,pickupTime;
    private DatePickerDialog.OnDateSetListener onDateSetListenerPickup;
    private DatePickerDialog.OnDateSetListener onDateSetListenerDropoff;
    private TextView viewPickupDate,viewPickupTime;

    private  Button submitBooking;

    String format;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_customer_booking);

        pickupDate=(Button) findViewById(R.id.buttonPickupDate);
        viewPickupDate=(TextView) findViewById(R.id.viewPickupDate);
        pickupTime =(Button) findViewById(R.id.buttonPickupTime) ;
        viewPickupTime=(TextView) findViewById(R.id.viewPickupTime);

        submitBooking = (Button) findViewById(R.id.submitDateTime);

        pickupDate.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                Calendar cal = Calendar.getInstance();
                int year = cal.get(Calendar.YEAR);
                int month = cal.get(Calendar.MONTH);
                int day = cal.get(Calendar.DAY_OF_MONTH);

                DatePickerDialog datePickerDialog = new DatePickerDialog(CustomerBookingActivity.this,android.R.style.Theme_Holo_Light_Dialog_MinWidth,
                        onDateSetListenerPickup,year,month,day);
                datePickerDialog.show();

                datePickerDialog.getWindow().setBackgroundDrawable(new ColorDrawable(Color.TRANSPARENT));
                datePickerDialog.show();
            }
        });

        
        pickupTime.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                Calendar time1 = Calendar.getInstance();

                int hour= time1.get(Calendar.HOUR);
                int minute=time1.get(Calendar.MINUTE);

                selectedTimeFormat(hour);

                final TimePickerDialog timePickerDialog= new TimePickerDialog(CustomerBookingActivity.this,
                        new TimePickerDialog.OnTimeSetListener() {
                            @Override
                            public void onTimeSet(TimePicker view, int hourOfDay, int minute) {
                                viewPickupTime.setText(hourOfDay + " : " + minute);

                            }
                        },hour,minute,true);
                timePickerDialog.show();
            }
        });

        
        onDateSetListenerPickup = new DatePickerDialog.OnDateSetListener() {
            @Override
            public void onDateSet(DatePicker datePicker, int year, int month, int day) {
                month = month + 1;
                Log.d(TAG, "onDateSet: yyyy/mm/dd: " + year + "/" + month + "/" + day);

                String date = year + "/" + month + "/" + day;
                viewPickupDate.setText(date);
            }
        };

        onDateSetListenerDropoff = new DatePickerDialog.OnDateSetListener() {
            @Override
            public void onDateSet(DatePicker datePicker, int year, int month, int day) {
                month = month + 1;
                Log.d(TAG, "onDateSet: yyyy/mm/dd: " + year + "/" + month + "/" + day);

                String date = year + "/" + month + "/" + day;
                viewDropoffDate.setText(date);
            }
        };

        submitBooking.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
              AddBooking();

            }
        });


    }

    public void selectedTimeFormat(int hour) {

        if (hour == 0) {
            hour += 12;
            format = "AM";
        } else if (hour == 12) {
            format = "PM";
        } else if (hour > 12) {
            hour -= 12;
            format = "PM";
        } else {
            format = "AM";
        }
    }

    public void AddBooking(){
        final String pickupDate = this.viewPickupDate.getText().toString().trim();
        final String pickupTime = this.viewPickupTime.getText().toString().trim();
        final String dropoffDate = this.viewDropoffDate.getText().toString().trim();
        final String dropoffTime = this.viewDropoffTime.getText().toString().trim();

        StringRequest stringRequest = new StringRequest(Request.Method.POST, ConstantURL.URL_CREATE_BOOKING,
                new Response.Listener<String>() {
                    @Override
                    public void onResponse(String response) {
                        try{
                            JSONObject jsonObject = new JSONObject(response);
                            String success = jsonObject.getString("success");

                            if (success.equals("1")) {
                                Toast.makeText(CustomerBookingActivity.this, "Success!", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                            }
                        } catch (JSONException e) {
                            e.printStackTrace();
                            Toast.makeText(CustomerBookingActivity.this, "Error! " + e.toString(), Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();

                        }
                    }
                },
                new Response.ErrorListener() {
                    @Override
                    public void onErrorResponse(VolleyError error) {
                        Toast.makeText(CustomerBookingActivity.this, "Error! " + error.toString(), Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();

                    }
                })
        {
            @Override
            protected Map<String, String> getParams() throws AuthFailureError {
                Map<String,String> params = new HashMap<>();
                params.put("pickupDate",pickupDate);
                params.put("pickupTime",pickupTime);
                params.put("dropoffDate",dropoffDate);
                params.put("dropoffTime",dropoffTime);
                return params;
            }
        };

        RequestQueue requestQueue = Volley.newRequestQueue(this);
        requestQueue.add(stringRequest);

    }
}
```

here is my php code:

```html
<?php

if ($_SERVER['REQUEST_METHOD'] =='POST'){

    $pickup_date = $_POST['pickup_date'];
    $pickup_time = $_POST['pickup_time'];
    $reference_no = uniqid();


    require_once 'connect.php';

    $sql = "INSERT INTO booking (reference_no, pickup_date, pickup_time) VALUES ('$reference_no', '$pickup_date','$pickup_time')";

    if ( mysqli_query($conn, $sql) ) {
        $result["success"] = "1";
        $result["message"] = "success";

        echo json_encode($result);
        mysqli_close($conn);

    } else {

        $result["success"] = "0";
        $result["message"] = "error";

        echo json_encode($result);
        mysqli_close($conn);
    }
}

?>
```

When i run my code in postman.The data can save into the database.But when i try to run my code in android studio, the data cannot save. I already check my format in database. The date format in database is yy/mm/dd.

Please help me to save user date and time into the database. Thank you in advance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Make sure you have below settings exists in your PHP and MYSQL .
MYSQL Side
- in your MYSQL table (booking)  - 2 columns pickup_date - Date Type should be date (yyyy-mm-dd) formatted input is expected to come to insert , pickup_time -this column data type should be time.

PHP Side :
Your posted date must be in format of yyyy-mm-dd if not than you have to convert it in this format only. You are posting from your Android code in this format : yyyy/mm/dd
time - will be expected in hh:ii:ss format only , you are posting time in AM/PM format.

Just update your inputs and it will work.

i assume you have properly written code in Android to do HTTP POST on your server ( Localhost Or Remote whereever your PHP and DB is located.)

Thanks.